# SQLite ORDER BY string containing number starting with 0

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, sql-order-by, numeric

as the title states:

I have a select query, which I'm trying to "order by" a field which contains numbers, the thing is this numbers are really strings starting with 0s, so the "order by" is doing this...

```
...
10
11
12
01
02
03
...
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: if I do this: "...ORDER BY (field+1)" I can workaround this, because somehow the string is internally being converted to integer. Is this the a way to "officially" convert it like C's atoi?

Comment: How are you getting that result? Are you sure the strings just have leading zeros or are the leading spaces involved as well?

Comment: The string doesn't have leading spaces. I was trying to find a way to sort strings containing numbers (1,2,3...,10,11,12) without them being sorted in the 1,10,2,3,4,5 fashion. I appended manually the leading 0, I tried with spaces too, but I see now casting the column to INTEGER was the smartest thing to do in the first place.

Comment: But `'01'` should come before `'10'` when they're sorted as strings, hence my curiosity. Or are you saying that you really have `'1'` rather than `'01'` in the database?

Comment: I was curious about it too, '01' should come before '10' sorted as strings, the previous sort mechanism was a plain ORDER BY value. I know it's not the jtable which re-sorted the rows, I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use `CAST` http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr to cast the expression to an Integer.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE T (value VARCHAR(2));
sqlite> INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES ('10');
sqlite> INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES ('11');
sqlite> INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES ('12');    
sqlite> INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES ('01');
sqlite> INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES ('02');
sqlite> INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES ('03');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY CAST(value AS INTEGER);
01
02
03
10
11
12
sqlite>
```

> if I do this: "...ORDER BY (field+1)" I can workaround this, because somehow the string is internally being converted to integer. Is the a way to "officially" convert it like C's atoi?

Well thats interesting, though I dont know how many `DBMS` support such an operation so I don't recommend it just in case you ever need to use a different system that doesn't support it, not to mention you are adding an extra operation, which can affect performance, though you also do this `ORDER BY (field + 0)` Im going to investigate the performance

taken from the sqlite3 docs:

> A CAST expression is used to convert the value of  to a different storage class in a similar way to the conversion that takes place when a **column affinity** is applied to a value. Application of a CAST expression is different to application of a column affinity, as with a CAST expression the storage class conversion is forced even if it is lossy and irrreversible.
>
> 4.0 Operators
> All mathematical operators (+, -, *, /, %, <<, >>, &, and |) cast both operands to the NUMERIC storage class prior to being carried out. The cast is carried through even if it is lossy and irreversible. A NULL operand on a mathematical operator yields a NULL result. An operand on a mathematical operator that does not look in any way numeric and is not NULL is converted to 0 or 0.0.

I was curios so I ran some benchmarks:

```
>>> setup = """
... import sqlite3
... import timeit
... 
... conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
... c = conn.cursor()
... c.execute('CREATE TABLE T (value int)')
... for index in range(4000000, 0, -1):
...     _ = c.execute('INSERT INTO T (value) VALUES (%i)' % index)
... conn.commit()
... """
>>> 
>>> cast_conv = "result = c.execute('SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY CAST(value AS INTEGER)')"
>>> cast_affinity = "result = c.execute('SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY (value + 0)')"
>>> timeit.Timer(cast_conv, setup).timeit(number = 1)
18.145697116851807
>>> timeit.Timer(cast_affinity, setup).timeit(number = 1)
18.259973049163818
>>>
```

As we can see its a bit slower though not by much, interesting.

Comment: thanks for the benchmark! Maybe the +0 operands get optimized out before being executed at all, if that's the case, +1 or +random would definitely lead to a slower query.

Comment: yep about `1%` slower vs `+ 0` go figure :)

Comment: What happens if the field(Column value) is empty or null

Answer (score 34):

You could use `CAST`:

```
ORDER BY CAST(columnname AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: Is this is correct format ORDER BY CAST(columnname AS INTEGER) ='01'

Answer (score 3):

In ListView with cursor loader!

```
String projection= some string column;
String selection= need to select;

String sort="CAST ("+ YOUR_COLUMN_NAME + " AS INTEGER)";

CursorLoader(getActivity(), Table.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sort);
```

Answer (score 1):

CONVERT CAST function using order by column value number format in SQL SERVER

SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY CAST(COLUMNNAME AS INT);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Skinnynerd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489095/8313609). with Kotlin, CAST worked as follows:
CAST fix the problems of prioritizing 9 over 10 OR 22 over 206.

define global variable to alter later on demand, and then plug it in the query:

```
var SortOrder:String?=null
```

to alter the order use:

For descendant:

```
 SortOrder = "CAST(MyNumber AS INTEGER)" + " DESC"
```

(from highest to lowest)

For ascending:

```
 SortOrder =  "CAST(MyNumber AS INTEGER)" + " ASC"
```

(from lowest to highest)