# What is the most efficient way to convert String numbers to Integers in SQLite, in order to sort by highest value?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two columns in my SQLite Database, name and score. I need to display the out put of all table records by score descending from highest value. I have this working at the moment but due to score being a String, of course it only goes by the first number in the string, so 30 is above 200 etc...

Here is my SQL code:

```
private static final String fields[] = { "name", "score", BaseColumns._ID };
Cursor data = database.query("scores", fields, null, null, null, null,  "score DESC");
```

I have no idea how I can continue to use the above code as well as converting all of the score values to integers in order to sort by highest score first. I started to do this by converting each score value into an integer and store it in an array in order to sort them, but then I only have half of my information, so this was a bad idea, I had not thought through.

I spent about an hour reading the SQLite documentation in order to seek some way of doing this more efficiently as well as scour Stackoverflow, but to no avail. Can anyone provide advice on how I should proceed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489098/1930331) solves the problem by casting the strings as integers in the query. This is better than doing it in the program because the database is built for storing and sequencing large amounts of data, so it is much more efficient to change the query than the code.

Comment: I used the code in here and it worked perfectly! I never new this could be done, thanks for point this out, it was much better than sorting all code converting the string to an int! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think the right answer is to store them as their correct type, since you only do that once when you INSERT.  Why reformat every time you query and display?  Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I read somewhere that you can only store text types in SQLite in Android, is this correct or can I use the integer data type in Android?

Comment: integer works just fine. Just no boolean. Nothing special about androids sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I could use integers, I have no idea where I read I could only use text. I used the cast option as that was my quickest solution! Thank you!!! :)