# Sort order in content provider

Tags: android

I created "book" table.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (`bcode` TEXT, `author_name` TEXT, `book_name` TEXT, `price` TEXT); ");
```

Then, I put my data like this.

```
" insert into book values ('1', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀' ); ",
  " insert into book values ('2', 'မင္းတေခတ္', 'သူသာ', '၁၅၀' ); ", 
  " insert into book values ('3', 'မင္းတေခတ္', 'သူသာ', '၁၀၀' ); ", 
  " insert into book values ('4', 'ေညး', 'တခါက', '၁၀၀' ); ", 
  " insert into book values ('5', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀' ); ", 
  " insert into book values ('6', 'လြန္းထားထား', 'တခါက', '၁၀၀' ); ", 
  " insert into book values ('7', 'အၾကည္ေတာ္', 'သံုည', '၁၀၀'); ", 
  " insert into book values ('9', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀'); ", 
  " insert into book values ('10', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀'); ", 
  " insert into book values ('11', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀'); ",};
```

when  i sort first column "bcode" by 'ASC' , the output is like this.

```
'1', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀' 
'11', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀'
'2', 'မင္းတေခတ္', 'သူသာ', '၁၅၀'
.
.
```

I want to get order like in this form.

```
'1', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀' 
'2', 'မင္းတေခတ္', 'သူသာ', '၁၅၀'
.
.
.
'11', 'ေညး', 'တခါက',  '၁၀၀'
```

How can  I sort?

Comment: `bcode` is an integer value? if your answer is yes so change type of that from `TEXT` to `INTEGER` in db, this will solve your problem

Comment: no. I want to use "bcode" as TEXT.

Comment: using `bcode` as `TEXT` will sort it as text and as I explained in my answer will sort just like your contacts are sorted in your phone. 

Sorting of text is different from sorting of numbers

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489055/sqlite-order-by-string-containing-number-starting-with-0 , maybe can help you

Comment: I got it. I changed it to INTEGER. Thanks for your explaination

Comment: it helps me totally. Thanks so much.  @shayan pourvatan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so because you are declaring `bcode` as `TEXT`, change it to `INTEGER`

Being Text it is sorted char by char and hence anything starting with `1` will always be displayed before the one that starts with `2` if you are sorting by ascending

Another approach that you can use if you insist to use `TEXT` for type of bcode is that you fix the maximum length of `bcode` and use leading zeros. If you decided 4 as the length so your `bcodes` should look like `0001,0002,0003 ... 0011,0012...1111 ...`

Answer (score 1):

your `bcode` type is `TEXT` just change your data type to `INTEGER`